# Inconsistent underline thickness in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I would like content of my anchor links to be consistenly bold and underlined, but spans inside anchor tag should not be bold.

Sample markup:

```
<a>Hello, <span>fooooo</span> bar</a>
```

Styles:

```
    a {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    span {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

[image]
*(right click on image and select view/open in new tab to get a better view)*

In IE8+, underline thickness is inconsistent: apparently it is determined by percentage of bold text inside link. Is there a way to make underlining look exactly the same for *every* link on the page?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FfBGn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kinda hack-ish, but instead of `text-decoration:underline`, you could use this instead:

```
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
```

[***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/UrztG/)

---

Alternatively, if you have to use `text-decoration:underline`,
you could just make bold **bolder**.

```
font-weight:800;
```

[***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/aJSNj/)

Comment: I could, but what if I wanted to, say, set display: block and some width on my anchors? Like implementing context ads or search suggestions? Border-bottom would get nasty very quick. Looking for more universal solution.

Comment: The alternative relies on browser bugs. Setting `font-weight: 800` is equivalent to `font-weight: bold` here, by the specs. There is no weight 800 typeface of Arial, Verdana, or browsers’ `sans-serif` fonts (and the “trebuchet” font of your example does not exist). So the weight used should be the nearest available weight, `bold` (= 700).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an easier way could be to set the border of the anchor instead of underline? That way you can dictate the thickness yourself?

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
```